# How to direct sort by using one parameter?

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot

I use order by cases like this:

```sql
       ORDER BY 
            CASE @sort WHEN 'a' THEN A END,
            CASE @sort WHEN 'b' THEN B END,
            CASE @sort WHEN 'c' THEN C END
```

How can I direct the sort in search case by using some text behind them. Example: `a.asc` then ascending, `a.desc` then descending in the URL but only use parameter sort? I'm using spring boot.

Comment: This type of logic isn't normally a good idea, and it *normally* requires dynamic SQL. If the User wants to chose the sort order, give them a way to do so by sorting it in the presentation layer, rather than the RDBMS.

Comment: ```larnu``` in spring boot how I can sort by add text behind parameter?

Comment: I read the document but they just show the URL not the way they make it.

Comment: What are the types of the `A`, `B`, and `C` columns?

Comment: It's just the name of columns that I test. Don't mind it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER
    BY CASE @sort = 'a' AND @direction = 'asc'  THEN A ELSE NULL END ASC
     , CASE @sort = 'a' AND @direction = 'desc' THEN A ELSE NULL END DESC
     , CASE @sort = 'b' AND @direction = 'asc'  THEN B ELSE NULL END ASC
     , CASE @sort = 'b' AND @direction = 'desc' THEN B ELSE NULL END DESC
     , CASE @sort = 'c' AND @direction = 'asc'  THEN C ELSE NULL END ASC
     , CASE @sort = 'c' AND @direction = 'desc' THEN C ELSE NULL END DESC
;
```

Comment: What's the need of `ELSE`?

Comment: Syntactical completion. Some linters will moan if you don't include an `ELSE` condition`.

Comment: but you are using 2 parameters? Maybe there is another way to use 1 parameter in spring boot?

Comment: `CASE WHEN @sort = 'a.asc' THEN A ELSE NULL END ASC, CASE @sort = 'a.desc' THEN A ELSE NULL END DESC...`